# How to append a random number to a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a random number to a string and then parse that as a variable name in my innerHTML.

```
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

var description1 = "This is description 1";
var description2 = "This is description 2";
var description3 = "This is description 3";

var desc = "description" + a;
var div = document.getElementById('result');
div.innerHTML += desc;
```

I get returned, for example, "description1", but not "This is description 1". How would one come around this?

Comment: Strings are not automagically converted to variables. Use array instead of "indexed variables".

Comment: Well you're not getting >This is description 1 because you are appending `desc` to the `div`'s `innerHTML`, and your `desc` variable is `"description" + a`, so I don't see what the problem is? You are not using `var description1` anywhere?

Comment: @filipbarak OP expects `desc` with the value `description1` to refer to `description1` variable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fun if JavaScript did behave like this? Creates a whole new challenge when naming variables and functions

Comment: @Yule Yup, and it also would cause massive difficulties when trying to use regular strings = ). Almost anything would trigger a reference error ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not append a interger to a variable name like this. Instead, you should use array to achieve this.

```js
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3));

var description = Array(3);
description[0] = "This is description 1";
description[1] = "This is description 2";
description[2] = "This is description 3";

var desc = description[a];
var div = document.getElementById('result');
div.innerHTML += desc;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference variables by name using bracket notation...

```js
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

var description1 = "This is description 1";
var description2 = "This is description 2";
var description3 = "This is description 3";

var desc = "description" + a;
var div = document.getElementById('result');
div.innerHTML += window[desc];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

However, this requires using the global window scope, which is not a good idea.  It pollutes the window object which is used by all scripts.  You could simply make an array (as per the other answer from void), or create an object and use that instead of `window`...

```js
var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 3) + 1);

var descriptions = {
    description1: "This is description 1",
    description2: "This is description 2",
    description3: "This is description 3"
};

var desc = "description" + a;
var div = document.getElementById('result');
div.innerHTML += descriptions[desc];
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```